# Too many clocks on the Budgie Panel

Tags: panel, clock, applet, budgie

I have 3 clocks on my Budgie Panel. One clock is on the left side of the top Panel and the other two are in the center. How to remove the two extra clocks, and keep the default clock in the center of the Panel?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. just select the applet in the top panel and use arrows to move them or X to delete them.

[image]